# I'm having trouble converting this Python function to a Swift function

Tags: python, arrays, swift

I'm working on this blackjack app for iOS and I'm having trouble getting the function to work properly.  I built it in Python where it works like a charm, but something is wonky when I adapt it.  The idea is to get every possible value of the cards.  Once I get that working, I'll sum up the numbers.  So, a `[[1,11],[4],[5]]` will output `[10,20]`.

Python code

```py
init_array = [[1,11],[3],[4],[1,11],[5]]
r = [[]]
for x in init_array:
    t = []
    for y in x:
        for i in r:
            t.append(i + [y])
    r = t
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 1, 5], [11, 3, 4, 1, 5], [1, 3, 4, 11, 5], [11, 3, 4, 11, 5]]
```

Swift code

```swift
var init_array = [[Int]]()
init_array.append([1,11])
init_array.append([3])
init_array.append([4])
init_array.append([1,11])
init_array.append([5])

var r = [[Int]]()
for x in init_array {
    var t = [Int]()
    for y in x{
        for i in r {
            t.append(contentsOf: (i + [y]))
        }
    }
    r = [t]
}
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 11, 5]]
```

It's part of a larger function, so creating the `init_array` variables and printing the r variables for both examples is for testing purposes.  The init_array has already been generated by the time it gets to my trouble code.

It's probably one simple line of code, but I've been trying to figure this out for days.  I'm relatively new to Swift, so this might take someone more advanced two seconds to figure out.

Comment: try printing init_arraybefore looping, see if its same as the python list

Comment: Hey Sandrin.  The output for init_array prior to looping is [[1, 11], [3], [4], [1, 11], [5]]

Comment: When you initialised `r`:
In python , length of `r` is `1` where as in swift the length is `0`. This is because, in python `r` is initialised with an empty list in inside it `[[]]`. But in swift, it didn't happen `[]`. This resulted in getting unwanted output.

Finally I found a way to fix it  by appending an empty list into `r` in the beginning.

    var r = [[Int]]()
    var temp=[Int]()
    r.append(temp)

Comment: Even tho i am not a swift coder :), finally i was able to find the bugs and solved it for your Please review it (PS : I am so excited too )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialised `r`:
In python , length of `r` is `1` where as in swift the length is `0`. This is because, in python `r` is initialised with an empty list in inside it `[[]]`. But in swift, it didn't happen `[]`. This resulted in getting unwanted output.

Finally I found a way to fix it  by appending an empty list into `r` in the beginning.

```
var r = [[Int]]()
r.append([])
```

Also `t.append(ContentsOf ...)` wasn't creating arrays as you wanted.

**Here is the final solution**

```
var init_array = [[Int]]()
init_array.append([1,11])
init_array.append([3])
init_array.append([4])
init_array.append([1,11])
init_array.append([5])

var r = [[Int]]()
r.append([])
print(r.count,r) // debuggging part
for x in init_array {
    var t = [[Int]]()
    for y in x{
        for i in r {

            //method 1 
            var dm=[Int]() //for making the kind of arrays u wanted
            dm.append(contentsOf: (i + [y]))  // appending it to array
            t.append(dm)
            // Or
            //method 2
            t+=[(contentsOf: (i + [y]))] as! [[Int]] //HereWeTypeCastToInt
        }
        print(t,y) // debuggging part
    }
    r = t
}
print(r)
```

Output : [[1, 3, 4, 1, 5], [11, 3, 4, 1, 5], [1, 3, 4, 11, 5], [11, 3, 4, 11, 5]]

Comment: Method 1 worked as is, but method 2 required me to fix some errors.  So I changed it to t+=[((i + [y]))] and didn't have any problems.  Thanks again!